# ¿Como puedo verificar un token que genero en mi aplicación flutter en mi servidor nodejs utilizando el sdk de firebase?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, jwt, express-session, google-oauth

Simplemente quiero verificar un token que genero en mi aplicación `Flutter` con `google firebase`.

Hago login correctamente obtengo el token de usuario pero cuando lo mandarlo a mi servidor `nodejs` no puedo verificarlo.

Primero intente verificarlo con `Jsonwebtoken` sin éxito luego he configurado el `sdk` como pone en la documentación:

[image: Documentación de Google]

Genero la clave privada la importo del `json` e inicializo el `sdk`

He visto otra configuración pero esta no vale ya que si la pongo dice que no encuentra la propiedad `pricate_key` esta es la configuración de google:

[image: Configuración en google del proyecto]

situado en General de la consola:

[image: Configuración consola]

he probado muchísimas cosas pero por ultima os dejo este código queriendo validar utilizando el sdk de google:

```
export const validarJWTGoogle = async (req, res = response, next) => {

    //Leer token
    const token = req.header('x-token');
    if(!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'No hay token en la petición'
        });
    }

    const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, {
        complete: true
    });
    //obtengo el kid para saber que certificado usar
    const kid = decodedToken.header.kid;
    //Obtengo los certificados de google
    const response = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com');
    let allCert = response.data;
    const cert = allCert[kid];
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
        .then((decodedToken) => {

            const uid = decodedToken.uid;
            console.log(uid);
        })
        .catch((error) => {

            console.error(error);
        });

};
```

El error que me da siempre es:

[image: Imagen del error]

También he intentado verificar el token con este código de **jsonwebtoken**:

```
jwt.verify(token, cert, (err, decoded) => {
            if(err) {
                console.error('Error al verificar el token:', err);
                else {
                    console.log('Token verificado correctamente:', decoded);
                }
            });
```

Consiguiendo el mismo error

He verificado en la pagina: https://jwt.io/ que el token sea correcto y lo es.

También he verificado los certificados que devuelve google y que se obtenga el de mi valor del token en el parámetro kid.

No sé que más probar muchísimas gracias de antemano agradecería cualquier documentación lo que sea.

He probado con el `sdk` de google y con `jsonwebtoken`.

He verificado que el token este correcto que el archivo `.json` que me da google para inicializar este correcto.

He borrado el proyecto, lo he vuelto a configurar y he generado otra vez el `json`.
He probado a meter la configuración en una variable de entorno en mi sistema.